# putting file-scope variables inside a struct? What is the benefit

Tags: c

As a C developer I always used to place file-scope variables as their own variable.

```
static char myChar;
static char *myCharPtr;
```

Now I've started people seeing to be placing these variables inside a struct, as so:

```
typedef struct
{
    char myChar;
    char *myCharPtr;
} exampleData_s;

static exampleData_s myExampleData;
```

Why would one do this? What are the benefits? I only see downsides: more typing and it doesn't make things more readable.

Or am I missing out on benefits?

Comment: Sounds like OO brainwashing to me.  :P  The only benefit i see would be the ability to replace that data all at once.  (And even then, you'd have to clean up the old data first, if it consisted of pointers to stuff.)

Comment: This is very context sensitive. I don't think there is a benefit per se, but obviously, if these variables are somewhat related and together describe a logical entity in your program, then perhaps it is a good idea to place them in a structure, even if used only in one file. Other than that, I don't see any reason to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It reduces name space pollution, especially for simple variable names like `x`, `y`, `length` etc.  If you put those variables in a struct, there's no ambiguity about which variable you're referencing in the code.

---

For example, I've used this technique to gather statistics in various programs.

```
typedef struct
{
    int count;
    int failed;
    int insize;
    int outsize;
    int bloated;
}
    stStats;

static stStats stats;

int main( void )
{
    memset( stats, 0, sizeof(stats) );

    // the following code is pseudo code for illustrative purposes only (it doesn't compile)
    while ( !done )
    {
        stats.count++;

        if ( something bad happens )
            stats.failed++;
    }
}
```